# 8-bit png's get distorted when you upload them

Tags: assets

When I upload an 8-bit transparent png, it gets distorted. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Is your server using GD or Imagick?  If it's using the former, do you see it in the latter?

Comment: Installing Imagick has fixed the distortion issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome... would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for distorted 8bit png's is to install imagick on the server.

I'm running whm/cpanel and there were some hoops to jump through to get it installed. I installed it in terminal and then in WHM, I had to enable it for PHP.